# Is the Nissan V-6, 3L , of 2003 , an interference engine?

Tags: engine, nissan, timing-belt, frontier

A friend has Frontier with this engine and a mechanic told her the timing belt broke ( 160,000 miles). He just said it would be expensive to fix. To try to get a more detailed idea of how expensive , I am wondering if her 2003 Nissan V-6 ,3 L , ( USA) is an interference type engine .

Answer (score 1):

The engine in your friend's Frontier should either be a VG33E or VG33ER (supercharged version). These displace 3.3L and they are most definitely interference engines. If the belt broke, your friend is most likely looking at a lunched engine. It will most likely be expensive, not only to replace the engine, but the labor involved in it as well. The [VG33E engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissan_VG_engine#VG33E) is built here in the US, so I doubt you're going to find a JDM equivalent (but I could be wrong).